# On Heroku, does utilising Node.js prevent the need for queues + worker dynos for third-party API calls?

Tags: api, node.js, heroku, background-process, worker

The Heroku Dev Center on [the page about using worker dynos and background jobs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) states that you need to use worker's + queues to handle API calls, such as fetching an RSS feed, as the operation may take some time if the server is slow and doing this on a web dyno would result in it being blocked from receiving additional requests.

However, from what I've read, it seems to me that one of the major points of Node.js is that it doesn't suffer from blocking under these conditions due to its asynchronous event-based runtime model.

I'm confused because wouldn't this imply that it would be ok to do API calls (asynchronously) in the web dynos?  Perhaps the docs were written more for the Ruby/Python/etc use cases where a synchronous model was more prevalent?

Answer (score 5):

NodeJS is an implementation of the [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern). The default build of of NodeJS uses 5 reactors.  Once these 5 reactors are being used for IO bound tasks, the main event loop will block.

A common misconception about NodeJS is that it is a system that allows you to do many things at once. This is not necessarily the case, it allows you to do other things while waiting on IO bound tasks, up to 5 at a time.

Any CPU bound tasks are always executed in the main event loop, meaning they will block.

This means if your "job" is IO bound, like putting things in databases then you can probably get away with not using dynos. This of course is dependent on how many things you plan on having go on at once.  Remember, any task you put in your main app will take away resources from other incoming requests.

Generally it is not recommended for things like this, if you have a job that does some processing, it belongs in a queue that is executed in its own process or thread.

Comment: Thx for the information about the 5 reactors.  What about querying a URL and waiting for a response?  The question refers particularly to third-party API calls.  Does this mean you can only have 5 at a time waiting for a response?

Comment: yes, that is correct.  If you are waiting on 5 api calls, it will not attempt to connect to the 6th until one of them completes. It will also not process any inbound requests, write to any files, to the console, database, or any other IO bound task.

Comment: Are articles such as this one (http://blog.nemikor.com/2010/05/21/long-polling-in-nodejs/) just plain wrong then?  Also this forum post "How would you server 100k simultaneous..." (https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/nodejs/0Z34PH_R88o).  It's a single Node.js process they are talking about.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I did not mean to make people think node can only handle 5 connections. That is not the case, node can handle as many connections as the server has handles. The reactors are for doing IO wait, this means actually sending data and waiting for a response.  In a long polling situation you are not always sending data (or waiting), even though the connections are open.